# How to play/pause playback on TuneIn?

Tags: big-sur

Big Sur now provides me with a media player icon in the menu bar.

However, I am unable to toggle playback while listening to a station on TuneIn.com.

Does anyone experience a similar problem and knows a solution?

In the below screenshot, clicking the pause button does not pause playback.

[image]